# Unable to delete the data in child entity in One-To-Many relationship

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot

I have 2 entities: Product and ProductLine. One Product can have many ProductLines. I am unable to delete the Product associated with a particular ProductLine.

**Product.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCT")
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

**ProductLine.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCTLINE")
@JsonSerialize
public class ProductLine {
    @JsonIgnore
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    public void setProducts(List<Product> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }

    private String name;
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "PRODUCTLINE_PRODUCT", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCTLINE_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ID"))
    private List<Product> products;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

You can find the entire code in - https://github.com/iftekharkhan09/ProductRepository.git

The Code is in Spring boot.

Please execute the below in postman:

1. Add product Line (POST)

http://localhost:8080/data/addProductLine?productLine=apple

2. Add Product to Product Line(POST)

http://localhost:8080/data/addProduct

body:

```
[
    {
        "productLine": "apple",
        "productName":"mac"
    }
    ,
    {
        "productLine": "apple",
        "productName":"iphone"  
    }
    ]
```

TO delete the Product(POST) :-
http://localhost:8080/data/deleteProduct?productLineName=apple&productName=mac

In the console I can not see the delete query being fired.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Provide the code of the repositories, please.

Comment: @NiVeR : Please check here the entire code is present -  https://github.com/iftekharkhan09/ProductRepository.git

Comment: Why is your delete metod marked as `RequestMethod.POST` even though it doesn't receive any body?